# NTP: Should I configure NTP step-tickers in a domain which uses local NTP servers?

Tags: centos6, ntp, ntpd

I've bumped into something which is called "NTP step tickers" and read about it in [this article](http://professionalvmware.com/2009/05/wtf-is-a-step-ticker-step-tickers-and-why-they-matters/), but I'm not sure if it's required in a domain which includes local NTP servers.

It seems like it replaces `/etc/ntp.conf` configuration file with `/etc/ntp/step-tickers` configuration file or is it supposed to be there in addition to the `/etc/ntp.conf` file?

Can anyone please shed some light on this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTPd famously, by default, won't adjust the time if it's more than 1000s out, presuming as it does that there's a systemic problem with which it shouldn't get involved.  This from `man ntpd`:

> ```
>    -g      Normally,  ntpd  exits  with  a  message  to the system log if the offset exceeds the panic
>            threshold, which is 1000 s by default. This option allows the time to be set to  any  value
>            without restriction; however, this can happen only once. If the threshold is exceeded after
>            that, ntpd will exit with a message to the system log. This option can be used with the  -q
>            and -x options. See the tinker command for other options.
> ```

One problem is that BIOS clocks in the UK are often an hour out, because of misunderstandings about whether the BIOS is in UTC or summer time.  I imagine the problem gets worse as your longitude from Greenwich increases.

So there is also a command `ntpdate`, which wrenches the system clock into alignment with an NTP server, in an unsubtle manner that tends to upset a lot of running services.  I believe it predates the addition of the `-g` flag to ntpd.

Thus, for old-timers like myself, the full startup protocol for `ntpd` involves the use of `ntpdate` to forcibly sync the clock - on the basis that that's safest to do when the system starts up - followed by starting `ntpd` to keep it there.  `/etc/ntp/step-tickers` controls which server is used to do the `ntpdate`.  I usually list one of my `ntp.conf` servers in there.

To further confuse the matter, the `ntpdate` startup script on CentOS6 will look in `ntp.conf` for a startup ticker if one isn't listed in `step-tickers`.  So whilst it is certainly good practice to make sure that `ntpd` won't be left high and dry (trying to sync a system clock that's too far out), between modern startup scripts and the `-g` flag to `ntpd`, `step-tickers` really is a historical relic, with no necessary function in a modern distro.  But I'm a historical relic, too, and so I continue to use it.